# How To Make My HTML5 Form Refresh On Its Own?

Tags: php, html, forms, submit

I have a contact form on my website, and once you click submit button, an echo message comes up but on a new page.

I want the page to automatically refresh when someone clicks submit, but also along with the echo message.

This is the HTML5 Code:

```
    <form method="post" id="form" action="send3.php" class="sendmail" onsubmit="return validateForm()" style="text-align:center;">


    <!-- Form Name -->

   <center><h2 class="">Contact Us</h2>



   </div>


  <center><label class="control-label">Your Email Address</label>

  <center><input type="text" id="eadd" name="eadd" class="input-xlarge" required>




  <center><label class="control-label">Topic of Message</label>

  <center><input type="text" id="top" name="top" class="input-xlarge" required>





  <center><label class="control-label">Message</label>


  <center><textarea id="mess" name="mess" required></textarea>



  <Br>

 <!-- Button -->

 <label class="control-label"></label>

 <div class="controls">   

 <center><input class="btn btn-primary"  type="submit">

     </div>
           </form>
```

Any Tips/Adivce would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sound like this is what you are looking for...

```
[myContactPage.php]

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') //Here you could check other items like referrer or some of your posted fields if you want
{
    //do whatever your current send3.php does
    //echo the result back out
}

<form method="post" id="myForm" action="myContactPage.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    [email field]
    [name field]
    [message field]
    etc...
    [submit button]
</form>
```